# Sonarqube administration and market place not visible

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I installed sonarqube and got the server running but I'm unable to

1. Add admin/users and secure my server
2. Find the marketplace where I can add more plugins.

Where can I find these options as the documentation isn't clear about it.

I'm using the Embedded database which comes with the basic installation.

Answer (score 1):

*SonarQube 8*: You need to activate http://localhost:9000, then activate the login button (top right). Default the user and password are 'admin'. The activate the menu 'Administration' and activate the Marketplace tab. In the plugins section on the page shown you can update or add plugins. When logged in, activate the button (top right) 'My account' and select security where you can change the admin password. When using the administration menu you can choose the security - users option to add more users. But never use the Embedded database in production! You can find the documentation using the http://localhost:9000/documentation link. Start reading the Instance Administration section.